# DoCmd.TransferDatabase vs Saved Import Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2007 database on my local PC and a copy out on a network share. I need to update the shared copy on a nightly basis. There are about 20 tables that need updated. Is there much difference between doing a `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` and creating an `UPDATE` query for each table?

Execution time isn't too much of a factor, since this will be automated and run in the middle of the night.

The structure of the tables won't be changing .. just the data.

If a user has an Access database saved to their local PC, and uses a table that's linked to the database I'm updating, does it matter which method I use to update it?

Thanks!

Comment: I reckon an update query would give you better error information. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834805(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: If you already have tables linked to the network back-end, why do you need to update anything? Do you have a duplicate set of local tables?

Comment: If your desktop copy is the master, and is not linked tables, why not copy the whole DB over.  Much faster than table by table?